# Photos for logos

Tags: logo

I am new to graphic design and  I need some help. I am currently making a logo for myself and I would like to have a photo as a background. When I wanted to purchase a photo, license states you can not use it for logo. Do you know where I can buy an image and then use it as a part of a logo??? Thank you for your information.

Sara

Comment: One question you should ask yourself is: _Should_ you use a photograph as a part of a logo? There's good reason why every big name company doesn't use a photograph as a part of its logo. Putting a logo over a photograph for a website or something is a different topic

Comment: @ZachSaucer - absolutely a good point.  "Should you" is perhaps much more important.

Comment: Neve include a photo, or raster images in a logo. (And often you don't want some "background" either.)

Answer (score 4):

**Disclaimer:** the following is not legal advice. You should contact a lawyer if you want legal advice.

The reason you can't use stock photographs for logos is because when you buy a stock photograph, it doesn't grant you copyright - only a licence to use the image. Stock photographs can be sold repeatedly, for anyone to use.

Logos on the other hand should be original creations which are copyrightable. If a logo were to contain a stock image, it wouldn't be copyrightable since you don't own the copyright.  You could never claim that logo as your own.

Perhaps your best bet is to take your own original photograph, or hire a photographer to take a photograph specifically for your own exclusive use, and who is prepared to sell you the copyright - which would mean nobody else could use it (not even the photographer).

Comment: Thank you for all your answers. I understand logo should be a vector file and it is but in this specific case I would like a backround for a special effect. So I guess it is best to take my own photo. All the best to you all!